# GTK+ errors in many operations

Tags: gtk

When I try `skype --secondary`, I get:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

With `sudo nautilus` I get:

```
(nautilus:15683): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

And I also get some other GTK+ warnings when installing for example VMware or other programs.

I get these errors, but everything works just fine, but I want to know why is this happening and how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are not *errors*, they are *warnings* or *messages*. The issues are, more often than not, minor programming mistakes or dependence on deprecated APIs etc.

You should not care about these, as long as the applications are working as expected. Unless if you are a developer of course.

---

In your Nautilus example, however, this is not even a real issue, the warning informs you that the current user does not have a D-Bus session, which is to be expected, if you are running it as root. Don't use `sudo` to run graphical applications, use PolicyKit instead:

```
pkexec nautilus
```

Comment: `pkexec` needs to be configured first to launch graphical applications. You would usually use `gksudo` or at least `sudo -H` instead.

Comment: `gksudo` (the original) is AFAIK deprecated. And the new `gksu` is using PolicyKit as its backend.

Comment: All true, but I think anyone with GTK experience will admit that GTK is, at times, overly verbose with non-issues that should probably be silenced.